# VS Code terminal doesn't recognize PATH variables

Tags: cmd, terminal, visual-studio-code

I added a directory to my PATH but the terminal in my VS Code doesn't recognize a command(exe) that I'm trying to run from that directory.
The terminal uses cmd not power shell.
What am I missing?

Comment: Where did you add a directory to your PATH? System level with SETX? Inside VS Code? Did you restart VS Code after adding it?

Comment: At a system level. Not inside VS code and I did restart VS code.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Not enough information in the question to provide an answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Restarted my computer and it worked :) Apparently VS Code didn't recognize the changes.

Comment: Thanks,, but i just restarted the VS code itself

Comment: In my case restarting VSCode didn't help, all built-in terminals didn't see the new PATH value. Singing out and in my Windows account helped.

Answer (score 22):

For me, a simple restart of VSC did the trick.

Comment: Note that 'Restart to Update' does not pick up the new PATH when it starts again.  Click X to close the app, check that the VS Code process is not present in Task Manager then open VS Code again, either from shortcut or by entering `code` in a cmd window.  Then it picked up the updated PATH.

Answer (score 8):

If your VS Code terminal shows "Session Restored" after restarting, then it may still be using the variables from before you rebooted! If this happens, close and re-open the vscode window, or kill and restart the terminal tab.

Comment: This was the answer for me. Persisted past a reboot!

Answer (score 5):

Clicking the bin/trash icon on the terminal to properly kill it and then CTRL + ' to open a new terminal works best. No need to close the app or shut down your PC.

[image]

Comment: A screenshot of this "bin icon" might help (not everyone calls the trash button a "bin"). Also, can do this through the command palette: "**Terminal: Kill the Active Terminal Instance**" and then "**Terminal: Create New Terminal**".

Comment: This didn't work for me. I installed terraform on my windows machine, and killed and launched a new terminal instance in vscode, yet powershell wouldn't recognize it (powershell recognized the name just fine when run outside of vscode).

But once I opened a new vscode window and ran terraform, it worked

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this problem can happen when you misuse .bash_profile and .bash_rc.

As mentioned in many materials, .bash_profile is executed for **interactive login shells**, and .bashrc is executed for **interactive non-login shells**.

VSCode terminal is **interactive non-login shells**. So, be sure you have correctly define your `PATH` and other environment variables in **.bashrc**

Answer (score 0):

I had some files remaining in the folder 'c:\Program Files\nodejs', deleted the folder and it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works and you don't want to restart your computer.

***For windows;***

1. Open a command prompt **(outside vscode)** and type `echo %PATH%`
2. Copy the path
3. Open your terminal in vscode and type `PATH=<your-path>` (replace <your-path> with the output)

**Note:** *This is a temporary solution and goes away if you close the terminal and open a new one.*

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had several VS Code instances opened, so I had to close all the opened instances in order to apply the changes

Answer (score -1):

For me, it turns out that VS Code was not on my Path even though it should have automatically been added after the install. This could be the case if you use the command 'code' and it is not recognized. Adding

```
C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
```

to my User PATH and restarting the terminal (and VS Code) fixed the issue on my machine.