# I got path error : [module not found] whenever I try to run any npm related command in VS Code

Tags: node.js, npm, path, environment-variables, npm-cli

Whenever I try to run any npm related command such as **npm -v** or **npm install** , it gives me the error:

[image]

From the screenshot, you can see that it is trying to navigate to find the module but the module can not be found at:

`C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js`

Actually, the location of the npm-cli in my system is:

`C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js`

In fact, I have set the path in the environment variable like this:

**User variables:**

[image]

**System variables:**

[image]

The solution I got is to run this command every time I want to run any npm related command:

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%
```

But it is not a solution to run this command in the terminal every time I start working on my project in VS Code. I want to permanently set the path in the environment variable.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Same issue, this was first major post I saw, so adding my fix for others who find themselves here. Hope it's helpful:

Restart PC, open VS Code, and delete any terminal instances that are still open, as they will not inherit the new path(s) if they are 'session-restored'.

My root cause was updating Node, which for whatever reason prefaced an environmental variable in $PATH$ with a semi-colon ';'. Worked in external cmd.exe, but didn't work in VS Code integrated terminal until I realized I had to restart the old ones.

This thread was the one that eventually got me there:
[VS Code terminal doesn't recognize PATH variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44868656/vs-code-terminal-doesnt-recognize-path-variables)

Comment: OMG, thank you! I was dying here. Everything was set but no single npm command was recognized. Closing terminals in IDE fixed the problem.

Comment: Since posting this, I started using WSL2 with VS Code, which includes bash terminal. Highly recommend setting up WSL2!